# implication of a locally trivial bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

I am following video lectures by Prof. Fredric Schuller titled "lectures on the geometrical anatomy of theoretical physics".In the following video 
[Manifold bundles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGEV0Wk0eIk&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&index=6)
at 1:07:25 he says that locally trivial bundle has an immediate implication that any section can be represented as a map from the base space to the fibre.What does that mean? I have been trying to dissect this statement for a long time but can't get my head around it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word is missing in the statement: "Any section of a locally trivial fibre bundle can be **locally** represented as a map from the base to the fibre."

Let $M\times N\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow}M$ be the trivial bundle over $M$ with fiber $N$, then a section of $\pi$ is $M\overset{\sigma}{\rightarrow} M\times N$ such that
$$\pi\circ\sigma=\operatorname{id}_M,$$
so that there is a bijective correspondence between sections of $\pi$ and maps from $M$ to $N$, given by:
$$f\mapsto(\operatorname{id}_M,f).$$
For a locally trivial bundle, this correspondence holds locally, since the bundle is locally isomorphic to $\pi$. Whence the affirmation made by F. Schuller.

I hope this discussion cleared things up for you, otherwise feel free to let me know!

Comment: I did not understand the bijective correspondence.Please elaborate. How is a section being mapped to a map from M to N?

Comment: Also, what does this mean "this correspondence holds locally"?

Comment: So, let $\sigma$ be a section of $\pi$, for all $x\in M$, one has $\sigma(x)=(x,f(x))$, $f$ is uniquely determined and is a map from $M$ to $N$. This gives the inverse of the map I have written in my answer. Regarding your other question, here is the meaning: let $p\colon X\rightarrow B$ be a fibre bundle, let $\sigma$ be a section of $p$, then for all $x\in B$, there exists $U$ an open neighborhood of $x$ in $B$ such that $\sigma_{\vert U}$ is represented by a map from $B$ to the fibre above $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!